# Convert UTC millisecond to UTC date in java

Tags: date

I am working in application where facing issue with time zones.

Want to convert UTC millisecond to UTC date object.

I already tried

```
   TimeZone utcZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC");    
   Calendar date = getInstance(utcZone);  
   date.setTimeInMillis(utcMillisecond);  
   date.getTime();
```

date.getTime is still returning my local time zone that is EST. I know that millisecond that I am getting from UI is in UTC millisecond.

Answer (score 1):

The old class java.util.Calendar silently applied your JVM’s current default time zone. You assumed it would be in UTC but it is not.

## java.time

You are using old troublesome date-time classes that have been supplanted by the java.time framework in Java 8 and later.

I assume that by "UTC millisecond" you mean a count of milliseconds since the first moment of 1970 in UTC, `1970-01-01T00:00:00Z`. That can be used directly to create a `java.time.Instant`, a moment on the timeline in UTC.

By the way be aware that java.time has nanosecond resolution, much finer than milliseconds.

```
Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli( yourMillisNumber );
```

Call `toString` to generate a String as a textual representation of the date-time value in a format compliant with the [ISO 8601](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard. For example:

> 2016-01-23T12:34:56.789Z